# Receiving error of incompatible JSON types for volley php interaction

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get data from a remote `database` via a `php` file and output the contents into a `ListView` container. When using test data (filling the data with strings and looping the creation of a `JSON` Object and then adding each object to a `JSONArray`) everything works fine. So I know the error must be in the following code:

```
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                String genreAddress = jsonResponse.getString("genreAddress");
                String blurb = jsonResponse.getString("blurb");

                    try {

                        JSONObject newListEntity = new JSONObject();
                        newListEntity.put("name", name);
                        newListEntity.put("genreAddress", genreAddress);
                        newListEntity.put("blurb", blurb);

                     jsonArray.put(newListEntity);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                ArrayList<GetDiscoverContent> getPanelContent = GetDiscoverContent.fromJSON(jsonArray);
                DiscoverAdapter adapter = new DiscoverAdapter(getContext(), getPanelContent);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    DiscoverDbRequest dbReq = new DiscoverDbRequest(tableType, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(dbReq);
```

Here is the LogCat for the error:

```
02-24 11:44:40.389 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type
org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
    02-24 11:44:40.389 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    02-24 11:44:40.389 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    02-24 11:44:40.399 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
    02-24 11:44:40.409 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic.DiscoverFragment$1.onResponse(DiscoverFragment.java:96)
    02-24 11:44:40.409 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic.DiscoverFragment$1.onResponse(DiscoverFragment.java:92)
    02-24 11:44:40.409 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    02-24 11:44:40.419 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    02-24 11:44:40.429 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    02-24 11:44:40.429 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-24 11:44:40.439 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-24 11:44:40.439 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-24 11:44:40.439 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    02-24 11:44:40.449 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
    02-24 11:44:40.449 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-24 11:44:40.459 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
    02-24 11:44:40.459 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
    02-24 11:44:40.459 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-24 11:44:41.069 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type
org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
    02-24 11:44:41.089 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    02-24 11:44:41.089 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    02-24 11:44:41.099 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
    02-24 11:44:41.099 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic.DiscoverFragment$1.onResponse(DiscoverFragment.java:96)
    02-24 11:44:41.109 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic.DiscoverFragment$1.onResponse(DiscoverFragment.java:92)
    02-24 11:44:41.109 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    02-24 11:44:41.109 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    02-24 11:44:41.119 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    02-24 11:44:41.119 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    02-24 11:44:41.129 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-24 11:44:41.129 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    02-24 11:44:41.139 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    02-24 11:44:41.139 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
    02-24 11:44:41.139 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-24 11:44:41.149 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
    02-24 11:44:41.149 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
    02-24 11:44:41.159 20391-20391/com.socialivemusic.socialivemusic W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone understand the error I'm getting? I have very similar code on a Login page and that works just fine for me.

Comment: Somewhere you are passing a JSONArray instead a JSONObject

Comment: Can you post a sample of the json you get? I think you're getting an empty json array, but a sample would help pinpoint the problem better.

Comment: This method `GetDiscoverContent.fromJSON(jsonArray)` does actually request JSONArray or JSONObject?

Comment: `jsonArray.put(newListEntity)` feels wrong... Why are you not putting `jsonResponse` immediately into the array?

Comment: @cricket_007 That is just left over from me messing around with it, meant to change that back. It doesn't effect the original error though. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JoséMª It does request an array and it works fine when using test information, so the error doesn't lie there.

Comment: Does the response start with a curly brace or a square bracket. That's the most simplest way to debug your error. JSONObject can't parse both

Answer (score 0):

`System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>()`

The only place that error can occur.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

The error message

> JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

So.. Parse **as a JSONArray**

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
```

Or... Use Volleys JSONArrayRequest class

Suggestion: Use Retrofit to handle your HTTP requests and JSON conversions in one pass